# How to get pairs from sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select, join

I am a database and I am just playing with sqlite3 for a group project.

I have two tables that look something like this:

```
Table 1:    
tv_show_id, tv_show_rating

Table 2:    
tv_show_id, cast_id
```

Each tv_show has 1 unique id, but in table two there are multiple cast_ids for each tv_show

So we have something like this:

```
Table 1: 
1234, 90
5678, 88

Table 2:
1234, "person 1"
1234, "person 2"
5678, "person 1"
5678, "person 3"
```

I want the following results: (person a, person b, # of shows together)

```
(person 1, person 2, 1)
(person 1, person 3, 1)
(person 2, person 1, 1)
(person 2, person 3, 0)
(person 3, person 1, 1)
(person 3, person 2, 0)
```

How can i use JOINS to get these results?

Comment: [So, did any of the answers solve your problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0252b/33)

```
select z.id,count(w.show_id) from
(
  select distinct concat(x.cid,',',x.did) as id
  from 
  (
   select tt.cast_id as cid,ttt.cast_id  as did
   from t2 tt,t2 ttt
   where tt.cast_id <> ttt.cast_id
   ) x
  left join t2  on x.cid = t2.cast_id
 ) z
left join (select show_id, group_concat(cast_id order by cast_id) cid
           from t2
           group by show_id
           union all 
           select show_id, group_concat(cast_id order by cast_id desc) cid
           from t2
           group by show_id
           ) w
on z.id = w.cid
group by z.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this (which might not be the most clever) would be to use a cross join to create a set of all possible pairs and the use a join and left join to determine if the pair have worked together.

In this query your source table is called `table2`:

```
select 
  cast1, 
  cast2, 
  sum(case when t2.cast_id is null then 0 else 1 end) as worked_together
from (
  select distinct 
    t1.cast_id cast1, 
    t2.cast_id cast2 
  from table2 t1,table2 t2 
  where t1.cast_id != t2.cast_id
) p
join table2 t1 on p.cast1 = t1.cast_id 
left join table2 t2 on t1.show_id = t2.show_id 
                   and p.cast2 = t2.cast_id 
                   and t1.cast_id != t2.cast_id
group by cast1, cast2;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/107d7/2) (tested with SQL.js). The query uses only ANSI SQL and is portable to other databases.

In some other databases you could have done this using a `full outer join` but SQLite does not support that construct.